# Using google cloud code editor

Tags: google-cloud-platform, code-editor

How to open files using code editor which is stored in compute engine created under google cloud? I can open for files stored using temporary cloud shell but not for the ones stored in compute engine.

Answer (score 2):

Google Cloud Shell code editor can only open files that are stored in your Cloud Shell home directory (which, by the way, is not temporary; unlike Cloud Shell VMs that are recycled, home directory persists between sessions).

Cloud Shell code editor is based on the open source [Orion](https://orionhub.org/) editor. If you like that editor, you can install it on your GCE VM and connect to it directly.

Comment: Yes I agree with Marat@ nice.

Comment: Hi @MaratB,  do you know how to connect Orion to the GCE VM? I register but could not find how to connect it. Thank you.